# grunt-contrib-sass compile multiple files in different modules best practice

Tags: css, angularjs, sass, gruntjs

What's the best way to structure and compile the scss files and the according css files within different modules?

My first thought was to compile every scss file into a css folder within a module but I cannot get this working.

My grunttask for this approach was

```
sass: {
  options: {
    style: 'expanded'
  },
  dev: {
    files: [{
      expand: true,
      cwd: 'public/modules/**/style/',
      src: '*.scss',
      dest: '../css',
      ext: '.css'
    }]
  }
}
```

according gruntfile code looks looks like this:

```
// Default task(s).
    grunt.registerTask('default', ['lint','sass:dev', 'concurrent:default']);
```

my folder structure:

```
/public
  /css
  /modules
    /core
      /css
      /scss
        core.scss
    /another-module
      /css
      /scss
        module.scss
  /style
    main.scss
```

Comment: Is compiling each module into its own CSS file a requirement? Or can everything just be compiled into `main.css`?

Comment: i would be just fine with compiling everything into a main.css, mostly I'm looking for a best practice

Comment: "Best practices" are opinions, and opinionated questions are frowned on.  We prefer "I'm trying to do X, but I'm getting error/problem Y" type questions.

Comment: thanks for the info, i will keep that in mind before asking questions again. I've used now grunt-contrib-concat to concat all scss files into a main.scss and compiling this file